# is there any Yii widget "Radio Button Set "?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm using bootstrap in my project and I want a Radio button set like the one in following [link](http://demo.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework/cjuibutton/index).

```
<?php $radio = $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton', array(
'name'=>'checkbox-btn',
'buttonType'=>'buttonset',
'htmlTag'=>'span',
)); ?>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" value="1" /><label for="check1">Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" value="2" /><label for="check2">Checkbox 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" value="3" /><label for="check3">Checkbox 3</label>
<?php $this->endWidget();?>
```

but this doesn't seem to work, it renders like a normal radioButtonList unsure emoticon 
I searched in yiistrap, yiiwheels, zii and yiibooster and couldn't find a widget similar to this " radios as buttons". 
Should I include jquery ui for this ? I prefer using already existing widget.
any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little heavy of a html portion, but does the trick:

```js
$($('#radio-btn').children()).click(function(){
    var input = $(this).is('input');
    input = input ? $(this).next() : $(this);
    $('.ui-state-active').removeClass('ui-state-active');
    input.addClass('ui-state-active');
    $('input').prop('checked','false');
    input.prev().prop('checked','true');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://demo.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework/assets/7c93f9e4/jui/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://demo.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework/assets/7c93f9e4/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio-btn" name="radio-btn" class="ui-buttonset">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="radio1" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Choice 1</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="radio2" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-left" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Choice 2</span>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <label for="radio3" aria-pressed="false" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-right" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Choice 3</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to make it checked when the page loads ? I tried `checked=true` but it's not working .

Comment: @user181452 combine setting checked to true and also add the class 'ui-state-active' to the following label

Comment: This works also , `$($('#radio-btn').children()).filter(':checked').next().addClass('ui-state-active');`

Comment: $('[for="' + $('#radio-btn:checked').attr('id') + '"').addClass('ui-state-acti‌​ve'); is even dumberer